Why don't I see my statements in the SQL Server trace file?
I've written a SQL-Server Profiler script file in order to see why some database actions are unsuccessful. The idea behind the script is:

Show me the starting statements (where an application starts writing something in the database)
Show me the finishing statements (where the mentioned application has finished writing something in the database)
Show me the "Attention" ones (where something goes wrong)

The script looks as follows:
DECLARE @TraceID INT;
DECLARE @MaxFileSize BIGINT = 50; -- File size limit in MB
DECLARE @TraceFilePath NVARCHAR(256) = N'C:\SQLTraces\Trace_OrderPart'; -- Base trace file path

-- Step 1: Create a new trace
EXEC sp_trace_create 
    @traceid = @TraceID OUTPUT,
    @options = 2, -- File rollover enabled
    @tracefile = @TraceFilePath,
    @maxfilesize = @MaxFileSize,
    @stoptime = NULL; -- No automatic stop


-- Step 2: Set events to capture
-- Add events to monitor SQL statements and related information
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16,  1, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) TextData
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16,  4, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) TransactionId
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16,  9, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) ClientProcessID
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16, 10, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) ApplicationName
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16, 11, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) LoginName
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16, 12, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) SPID
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16, 13, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) ClientProcessID
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16, 14, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) StartTime
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16, 15, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) EndTime
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16, 20, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) Severity
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16, 23, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) Success
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16, 25, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) IntegerData
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16, 27, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) EventClass
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16, 31, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) Error Number
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16, 34, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) ObjectName
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16, 49, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) RequestID
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 16, 55, 1; -- EventClass (SP:Attention) IntegerData2

EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40,  1, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) TextData
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40,  4, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) TransactionId
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40,  9, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) ClientProcessID
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 10, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) ApplicationName
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 11, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) LoginName
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 12, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) SPID
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 13, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) ClientProcessID
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 14, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) StartTime
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 15, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) EndTime
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 20, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) Severity
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 23, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) Success
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 25, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) IntegerData
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 27, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) EventClass
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 31, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) Error Number
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 34, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) ObjectName
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 49, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) RequestID
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 40, 55, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtStarting) IntegerData2

EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41,  1, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) TextData
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41,  4, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) TransactionId
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41,  9, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) ClientProcessID
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 10, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) ApplicationName
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 11, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) LoginName
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 12, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) SPID
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 13, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) ClientProcessID
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 14, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) StartTime
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 15, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) EndTime
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 20, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) Severity
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 23, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) Success
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 25, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) IntegerData
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 27, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) EventClass
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 31, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) Error Number
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 34, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) ObjectName
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 49, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) RequestID
EXEC sp_trace_setevent @TraceID, 41, 55, 1; -- EventClass (SP:StmtCompleted) IntegerData2

-- Step 3: Set a filter for the table CommandOrderParts
-- exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 34, 0, 6, N'%VehicleOrderPart%'; -- ObjectName filter
exec sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID,  1, 0, 6, N'%VehicleOrderPart%'; -- TextData filter

-- Optional: Output TraceID for reference
SELECT @TraceID AS TraceID;

-- Optional: Add a filter for ApplicationName to capture specific applications
-- EXEC sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 10, 0, 6, N'XClarys.Server'; -- Filter for XClarys.Server
-- EXEC sp_trace_setfilter @TraceID, 10, 1, 6, N'Cerastore.JBT'; -- Filter for Cerastore.JBT

-- Step 4: Start the trace
EXEC sp_trace_setstatus @TraceID, 1; -- Start the trace

-- Step 5: Stop the trace
-- EXEC sp_trace_setstatus @TraceID, 0; -- Stop the trace
-- EXEC sp_trace_setstatus @TraceID, 2; -- Stop the trace

The results look as follows:

The result of SELECT @@VERSION on that database is Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU31-GDR) (KB5029376) - 14.0.3465.1 (X64)   Jul 30 2023 15:31:58   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor).
I am looking at the *.trc file on my computer, where the result of SELECT @@VERSION equals Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM-GDR) (KB5046861) - 16.0.1135.2 (X64)   Oct 18 2024 15:31:58   Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0 <X64> (Build 19045: ) (Hypervisor).
The question is rather obvious: where are my starting and finishing statements???

Might be better to look into an Extended Event, so you can use causality tracking to find related statements.

@Peter: when I open the XEvent Profiler (Standard), I see around one thousand entries in just a matter of seconds. The problem I'm investigating happens once a week, even less, and I'm afraid blowing up my customer's memory and/or diskspace like that. Do you know a way to monitor XEvent Profiler in order to avoid such problems?

Peter is almost certainly not speaking about XEvent Profiler. Extended Events are under Management node in SSMS. Look into this answer on how to track failed queries with Extended Events. You don't need StmtStarting and StmtCompleted.

@rois: thanks for your reply. I'm still trying to modify my script in order to correspond with the items, mentioned in your answer. So what you are saying is that, next to StmtStarting (40) and StmtCompleted (41), which might be useful for SSMS actions, I also need rpc_started (10), rpc_complete (11), Batch_Starting (12) and Batch_Completed (13)?
